# Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API using Unity error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

Im trying to follow [this blog](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver) for implementing dependency injection with Unity but I'm getting an error in the boostrapper.cs (I use Unity.MVC4 library). Can someone point me what's I am missing here?

> ERROR:  IoCContainer does not
>   appear to implement
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator. Parameter name:
>   commonServiceLocator

```
 public static class Bootstrapper
    {
    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
      var container = BuildUnityContainer();

      DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

      // this throws "does not appear to implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator.... error"
      DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new IoCContainer(container)); 

      return container;
    }

    ....
  }
```

this is the IoCContainer class

```
public class ScopeContainer : IDependencyScope
    {
        protected IUnityContainer container;

        public ScopeContainer(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }
            this.container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
            {
                return container.Resolve(serviceType);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
            {
                return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<object>();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }

    class IoCContainer : ScopeContainer, IDependencyResolver
    {
        public IoCContainer(IUnityContainer container)
            : base(container)
        {
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
            return new ScopeContainer(child);
        }
    }
```

ADDITIONAL! Im calling the bootrapper in the app_start which I am not sure it its correct

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            Bootstrapper.Initialise();
        }
```

I also have a feeling that it might related to the routing, I actually added the classic MVC routing in the config as I read that webapi and mvc uses different "activator" stuff or somehing like that

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "RestApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: And remove all directly not related code to make the question more clear, please.

Comment: // this throws "does not appear to implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator.... error"

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer, seems like the blog is outdated as I dont even have to create the IoCContainer as I just need to install `Unity.WebAPI` and just set the `DependencyResolver` to `new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);`

```
public static class Bootstrapper
  {
    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
      var container = BuildUnityContainer();

      DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);

      return container;
    }
```

credit: http://netmvc.blogspot.com/2012/04/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html

Comment: Also worth looking at from the Unity team: [Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC](http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) and [Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET Web API](http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.AspNet.WebApi/).

Comment: so, is it acceptable to use GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver in your controller?